# Creating a forest plot separated by outcome from a multivariate meta-analysis using metafor

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor, forest-plot

I'm struggling to create a forest plot that separates the average effects by outcome. I ran a multivariate mixed effects meta-analysis with 6 outcomes, with 49 studies (some studies have effect sizes for all six outcomes; others have less). Here is the model and output:

```
main_model <- rma.mv(ES, variance, mods = ~ RELATION - 1,
              random = ~ RELATION | ID, 
              struct = "UN",
              slab = REF,
              data =df)
print(main_model, digits = 3)
```

[image]

[image]

Using the metafor package, I created a forest plot that has all of the outcomes combined, but how would I separate the outcomes either by different columns in one plot, or using separate plots by outcome? Below is my plot code and the top half of the forest plot output:

```
pdf("ForestPlot.pdf", family = "Helvetica", width = 12, height = 20)

par(mar=c(2.5,4,1,2.5), cex = .9, font = 1)

forest(main_model, 
       xlim = c(-2.5, 1.8),                 # adjust horizontal plot region limits
       addfit = F,                          # add standard summary polygon
       annotate = T,                        # remove annotations
       width = 0,                           # width of annotations
       efac = .55,                          # height of CI bars
       pch = 19,                            # changing point symbol to filled circle
       col = "gray40",                      # change color of points/CIs
       clim = c(-1 ,1),                     # set absolute limits for CIs
       cex.lab = 1,                         # increase size of x-axis title
       cex.axis = 1,                        # increase size of x-axis labels
       cex = .85,                           # set font expansion factor
       lty = c("solid",                     # CI line type
               "solid",                     # credibility interval line type
               "solid"),                    # horizontal line type
       xlab = "",                           # label X axis
       mlab = "RE Model: p = .04, I2 = 93.9",    # label summary estimate
       showweights=F,  
       ilab=df$RELATION, 
       ilab.xpos=-1.1, 
       steps = 5)                           # number of tick marks for the x-axis

par(cex = .9, font = 2)

text(-2.5, 120, "Study name", pos = 4, cex = .9)
text(1.8, 120, "Correlation and 95% CI", pos = 2, cex = .9)
text(-1.1, 120, "Outcome", font=2)

dev.off()

op <- par(cex = .9, font = 1)
par(op)
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: I would have thought that by judicious use of the order and rows parameters you could separate the outcomes and leave a gap between them. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean--can you say a little more? Are you saying to re-order the raw data before running it through? I'm less concerned about gaps between rows, and am looking to create one plot that has each outcome as a separate column title at the top (with the respective effect size under it). Alternatively, creating separate plots by outcome would be okay too (i.e. 6 separate plots separated by outcome). The latter option would just look like the screenshot but each plot would just include effects for that one outcome.